# How to pass compiler flags for Objective-C++ using CMAKE?

Tags: compilation, cmake, objective-c++

How can I replicate [QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-objective-cflags) using CMake - that is, pass compiler flags for Objective-C++ code?

Comment: CMake does not support Objective-C or Objective-C++.

Comment: It's compiling to me so that's enough support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "various flags")
```